# Measurable Subsets + Caratheodory Measurability

Tags: measure-theory

**1.) What can go wrong if one assigns a measure to more subsets, especially to all subsets?** *(I would like to understand the subtleties behind)*

I imagine the first problem is to give the new subset some number in a unique way. There, however, one could just try to choose one of several possible choices. But what happens next? Is it that countable additivity cannot hold anymore?

**2.) How come that Caratheodory's measurability argument works?**
*(I would like to understand the reason behind we restricting to these subsets make the outer measure become a measure*)

When I think of this problem I can imagine that picking another sigma algebra could turn the outer measure into a measure as well. Clearly all subalgebras of the one chosen by Caratheodory will make it too. But are there more than these?

For example, pick a vitali set and all rational translates of it. Take their outer measure. This should constitute another sigma algebra different from the one by Caratheodory's construction.

Comment: If I remember correctly there are a few different problems that can come up from including more. Just look at the non-measurable sets in the reals.

Answer (score 2):

If $\bar \mu$ is the *outer* lebesgue measure, there is a subset $A \subset [0,1]$ such that $$
  \bar\mu(A) = \bar\mu([0,1] \setminus A) = 1 = \bar\mu([0,1]) \text{.}
$$
That breaks the requirement that if $\mu$ is a measure and $X,Y$ disjoint subsets you always have $$
  \mu(X) + \mu(Y) = \mu(X \cup Y) \text{.}
$$
(Just set $X=A$, $Y = [0,1] \setminus A$, then $X,Y$ are clearly disjoint and $X \cup Y = [0,1]$)

Thus, the outer measure $\bar\mu$ is not a *measure*. The problem is, as the above shows, that $\bar\mu$ is not *additive*. Caratheodory's avoids that by allows only those sets $A$ which split *every* set $S$ into two parts - $S \cap A$ and $S \cap A^C$, such that the sum of the outer measures of these two parts is equal to the outer measure of $S$.

Pick two such allowed and disjoint sets $X,Y$. Set $S = X \cup Y$. Then $$
  \bar\mu(X\cup Y) = \bar\mu(S) = \bar\mu(\underbrace{S \cap X}_{=X}) + \bar\mu(\underbrace{S \cap X^C}_{=Y})
  = \bar\mu(X) + \bar\mu(Y) \text{,}
$$
which shows that for *allowed* sets, $\bar\mu$ is indeed additive.

Comment: Ok but caratheodory in here requires this split w.r.t. *all* subsets not just for those that will constitute the sigma algebra in the end ...so I guess when relaxing this one could as well choose the vitali set plus some other free choices and allow in the end only those ones that are conform with these few chosen ones - is this possible?

Comment: Besides as far as I know Caratheodory's construction already establishes a complete measure in general (in case of lebesgue not just the borel measure)...

Comment: @Freeze_S I removed the offending paragraph...

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Omega$ be a non- empty set. We define the Borel $\sigma$- algebra $B(\Omega)$ to be the intersection of all $\sigma$- algebras that contain the topology of $\Omega$.

Also let $M$ be the set of all measurables sets and $P(\Omega)$ be the power set of $\Omega$.

Then $B(\Omega)\subset M\subset P(\Omega)$ and also $B(\Omega)\neq M$,$M\neq P(\Omega)$.

So,for your first question we have Vitali's argument,that there exists a non measurable set http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set.

As for the second question we wanted the additivity. For example in the reals (where you can imagine it) we want $m(A\cup B)=m(A)+m(B) $ for measurable sets such that $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

First,we show that $m^{*}(X\cap(A\cup B))=m^{*}(Χ\cap A)+m^{*}(X\cap B) $. Then we show it for infinite many $A_i$ and after that we take $X=\Bbb R$ and we have the infinite additivity.

For me Caratheodory thought it vice versa. However it's hard to imagine it and somehow this definition came from the sky:P

Comment: But why do we want it to hold for any subset $X$?

Comment: if you want to measure something that can be measured you should measure it on any set $X$.

Comment: Why? I mean thats not what we necessarily require on measures... or do we? I don't mean that offensive I just would like to understand it ;)